# How to do i reconvert my binarizied image back to original image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, steganography

```
import cv2

im=cv2.imread('spider.png',-1)

cv2.imshow("original image",im)

cv2.waitKey(0)

gray_pic = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

r, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_pic, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

cv2.imshow('Binary Image',threshold)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: you cant, it's impossible. instead, keep the original image around

Comment: Converting color to gray and clipping pixel values are essentially removing information from the previous form of the image. Once information is removed it's impossible to recover the original.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because you lose information when you binarize the original image. You can only recover the original image when using [lossless compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32723255)

Comment: @EmiOB It's more than a link though. That said, it might help to add code that actually does this lossless compression.